# Terraform AWS bucket policy document, ARN gets changed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-kms

I'm having a strange issue where ARNs get changed at some point.  This is happening for both a bucket policy and KMS key policy.

In the policy document, I specify Role ARNs in an external account:

```
...
principals {
  type        = "AWS"
  identifiers = var.list_of_arns
}
...
```

The terraform plan output looks normal:

```
Principal = {
  AWS = [
    "arn:aws:iam::account-id:role/role1",
    "arn:aws:iam::account-id:role/role2",
  ]
}
```

However, the actual resources that get created are different.

```
{
  "Statement": [
  ...
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": [
      "SOMESTRINGOF21CHARS",
      "OTHERSTRINGOF21CHARS"
    ]
  }
  ..
}
```

Why is this happening?

Thanks

Comment: A complete minimal reproducible example would be nice

Answer (score 1):

It looks like terraform/aws is subsituting the user-friendly ARN with the equivalent ID. From the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_identifiers.html#identifiers-unique-ids):

> When IAM creates a user, group, role, policy, instance profile, or
> server certificate, it assigns to each entity a unique ID that looks
> like this:
>
> AIDAJQABLZS4A3QDU576Q
>
> For the most part, you use friendly names and ARNs when you work with
> IAM entities. That way you don't need to know the unique ID for a
> specific entity. However, the unique ID can sometimes be useful when
> it isn't practical to use friendly names.
>
> One example pertains to reusing friendly names in your AWS account.
> Within your account, a friendly name for a user, group, or policy must
> be unique. For example, you might create an IAM user named David. Your
> company uses Amazon S3 and has a bucket with folders for each
> employee. The bucket has a resource-based policy (a bucket policy)
> that lets users access only their own folders in the bucket. Suppose
> that the employee named David leaves your company and you delete the
> corresponding IAM user. But later another employee named David starts
> and you create a new IAM user named David. If the bucket policy
> specifies the David IAM user, the policy allows the new David to
> access information that was left by the former David.
>
> However, every IAM user has a unique ID, even if you create a new IAM
> user that reuses a friendly name that you deleted before. In the
> example, the old IAM user David and the new IAM user David have
> different unique IDs. You can create resource policies for Amazon S3
> buckets that grant access by unique ID and not just by user name.
> Doing so reduces the chance that you could inadvertently grant access
> to information that an employee should not have.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen when the AWS principals referenced in the policy no longer exist or when the policy is created before the principals are created.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).